# How to start Linux Oracle instance when I get ORA-01017 with dbstart?

Tags: linux, oracle

I have a RHEL box where I installed Oracle (12.1.0.2), and it was working fine.  I was even able to reboot and start the Oracle listener and instance once.  But, today is a new day of course, and now when I execute dbstart logged in as the "oracle" account, or if I simply start the listener, set $ORACLE_SID, and execute "sqlplus / as sysdba" - I get the following errors:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Aug 24 09:55:35 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SQL> SP2-0640: Not connected
SQL>
```

Also, if I take a look at /etc/oratab, autostart is set to Y.

Right now, the instance is not up.  PS does not show a running Oracle instance.  Here is a lsnrctl status.  How can I start it up at this point?

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rhel75x64three.inceptra.com)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                24-AUG-2020 09:39:29
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 20 min. 31 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/rhel75x64three-inceptra-com/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL>
```

Comment: Your SQL\*Plus output doesn't match the command you used; did you use `/nolog` and pass in the connect, maybe? If it worked before, what has changed? Has the server IP changed, or how rhel75x64three resolves - did/does it resolve to 127.0.0.1? Is the DB really down - `ps` doesn't show e.g. PMON for instance - or can it just not register with the listener (because of IP change maybe)? The ORA error implies you are connecting to something that is running, so have you maybe set TWO_TASK in your environment?

Comment: Yes, ps does not show a running instance (logged in as root, I do ps -ef | grep oracle and it comes back with nothing except the listener if I start that manually).  The server name resolves to its actual IP not the loopback.  IP address is static and hasn't changed.  I actually don't know what TWO_TASK is, so if it is not default I haven't set it.

Comment: I should add, the sqlplus output above is logged from the dbstart command.  Here is a shell session:    [oracle@rhel75x64three-inceptra-com administrator]$ export ORACLE_SID=RHELTHREE
[oracle@rhel75x64three-inceptra-com administrator]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Aug 24 11:52:35 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name:

Comment: TWO_TASK is just an env. variable (echo $TWO_TASK).  You mention being logged in as root.  You should never do oracle admin stuff as root. And that itself can be a source of problems in starting your db. In fact your should never do _anything_ as root that does not absolutely require that level of privilege.  You also mention dbstart.  I've been managing oracle db since about 1996 and cannot remember the last time I used dbstart. I just don't need it.

Comment: Also, as others mentioned, you do not show your actual sqlplus command.  But the very fact that you got a '1017' is proof-positive that somehow you attempted to connect to a database that very much _is_ up and running.  That error is returned _by the database_.

Comment: Another thing you can check is what you see with `sqlplus x/y` *without* `as sysdba`; does that also get ORA-01017, or ORA-01034? 1017 would mean you're connecting to something, but not what you think. 1034 means the DB is down - but then your original command should get 'connected to an idle instance', so something else has gone wrong (ownership, group, corruption somewhere...)

Comment: It simply states that TNS doesn't know of a connection with that descriptor.  Which means it isn't registered with the listener.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was sqlnet.ora.  The SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES was set to (NTS), which is not available on Linux.  Instead, I changed it to:

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (ALL,NONE)

Now, this works.